# How to set currentUser emailVerified: true in the browser (replace actual email verification)?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to let the users to verify their email by entering the code after signing up that they would receive. (to replace email verification)
What should be the way to set the "emailVerified" current user's object property to true?

```
if (userCodeInput === verificationCode) {

    currentUser.updateProfile({
    emailVerified: true,
    displayName: "name changed"

    }).then(function() {
    // Update successful.
    }).catch(function(error) {
    // An error happened.
    });
}
```

works for displayName but not for emailVerified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably can be done in the admin-sdk, but not on the client sdk.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

Which makes sense since user should not have the power to bypass the verification flow, but admins should.